# If $x^2 + y^2 = 1$, prove $x+y≤\sqrt2$

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

If $x^2 + y^2 = 1$, how do you prove $x+y≤\sqrt2$?

I'm really stuck (I think inequalities is involved, but I'm really bad at inequalities and rarely use them so.... ) I think C-S is involved, but I'm not sure.

This comes from a more complicated, larger problem, I've just broken it down to the bit on which I have no idea what to do.

Comment: Assume $x+y>\sqrt2$.  Take squares and conclude $xy>1$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show the following equality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2095681/show-the-following-equality). Your case is when $|z| = 1$.

Answer (score 3):

$$(x-y)^2\ge0$$
$$⇒ x^2+y^2\ge2xy=(x+y)^2-x^2-y^2=(x+y)^2-1$$
$$⇒ 1=x^2+y^2\ge(x+y)^2-1$$
$$⇒ 2\ge(x+y)^2$$
$$⇒ x+y≤\sqrt2$$

Answer (score 2):

Cauchy-Schwarz works, as you suspected. Define
$$\mathbf{u}=(x,y) \\ 
\mathbf{v}=(1,1) $$
We have
$$\mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{v} \leq \|\mathbf{u} \| \| \mathbf{v}\|, $$
or

$$x+y \leq \sqrt{2}.$$

Comment: Would be clearer with $x+y\le\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\sqrt{1^2+1^2}=\sqrt2$.

Answer (score 2):

$$x^2+y^2=1$$ is the unit circle, and

$$\cos(\theta)+\sin(\theta)=\sqrt2\cos\left(\theta-\dfrac\pi4\right)\le\sqrt 2.$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that if $x^2+y^2=1$, then by the Arithmetic mean-Geometric mean inequality
$$
|xy|=\sqrt{x^2y^2}\leqslant\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}=\frac{1}{2}
$$
Now, if $x^2+y^2=1$, then $(x+y)^2=1+2xy\leqslant 1+2|xy|$, so
$$
|x+y|\leqslant\sqrt{1+2|xy|}\leqslant \sqrt{1+2\cdot\frac{1}{2}}=\sqrt{2}
$$
as required QED.

Answer (score 1):

One could also consider a geometric perspective. The tangent line to the circle $x^2+y^2=1$ at the point $(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}, \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})$ is the line $x+y = \sqrt{2}$.

[image]

For a given point $P = (x_0,y_0)$ on the circle, if $c$ is the value of $x_0+y_0$, then the line $x+y = c$ intersects the circle in $P$. This line is parallel to the line $x+y = \sqrt{2}$, and $c$ will be less than or equal to $\sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let us solve

$$\begin{cases}x^2+y^2=1,\\x+y=\sqrt2.\end{cases}$$

Subracting the second multiplied by $\sqrt2$,

$$\left(x-\frac1{\sqrt2}\right)^2+\left(y-\frac1{\sqrt2}\right)^2-1=1-2$$
gives the only solution $\left(\dfrac1{\sqrt2},\dfrac1{\sqrt2}\right)$.

Hence all points are on the same side of $x+y=\sqrt2$, because a disk is convex.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $x+y>\sqrt2$, so that $y>\sqrt2-x$.

Then $x^2+y^2>x^2+2-2\sqrt2x+x^2=2x(x-\sqrt2)+2$.

The RHS is minimal when $x=\frac1{\sqrt2}$, and equals $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x+y>\sqrt{2}$

$$ x^2+y^2+2xy>2 $$

$$ 2xy>1 $$

We know that $(x-y)^2<0$ is not true.

$$ x^2-2xy+y^2 $$

$$ 1-2xy $$

Now see $2xy>1$ which will make $(x-y)^2<0$ which is false. Thus our assumption that $x+y>\sqrt{2}$ is wrong.